# How to link a selected set of files from one directory to another in Linux?

Tags: linux, symlink

Say for example, in the source directory I have the following files:

1. abc.r
2. xyz.sh
3. pqr.fam
4. lmn.bim
5. uvw.r
6. ttt.sh

Now I need to link only the items 1,2 and 5 only (listed above). Most importantly I need to link all the 3 files together (i.e. link all the 3 files at the same time).

I know how to link 1 file at a time (`ln -s sourceDirectory/fileName targetDirectory/`), but not multiple files at once.
I found ways to do this when the file name prefixes has some pattern (*for example, link all the files where the names start with letter "f"*), but in my case, I do not have any such pattern. My file names are different.

Comment: Specify what you mean by "link all the 3 files together".  You want to have 1 command create 3 links, or you `cat` 3 files together and link once, or ...  Also do you have any criteria to decide which file to link and which one not to?  Something that can be understood by a shell (file pattern, even a list)?  Missing details, and an attempt (see [mcve] and [ask]).

Comment: Thanks. In other words, "to link all the 3 files together" implies "link all the 3 files at the same time" (separately, not concatinating)

Comment: "do you have any criteria to decide which file to link and which one not to?" - no. There's no pattern or criteria or a deciding factor. Just a list of files that I need to link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in a.txt b.txt c.txt
do
    ln -s /sourcedir/"${file}" /targetdir/
done
```

Since you only have a list, you have to iterate through the list.

Comment: Rather than "Try this:", you may want to explain that there is no single command to create multiple links from various files in a directory. In that case you must iterate over each file and create a separate link for each. I know what you mean, but a little extra explanation goes a long way helping the student along....